# Firebase Auth: Manually detect if the current user has recently authenticated

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

By default, if the user signed in X time ago, Firebase will require him/her to reauthenticate via `reauthenticateWithCredential` in order to complete the action.

Is there a way to query the Firebase API if the user already qualifies for reauthentication before proceeding with next action?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying is the requirement. Did you read that somewhere?  Normally the Firebase Auth SDK will automatically refresh its ID token, and you have to do nothing.

Comment: @DougStevenson For certain sensitive operations the server requires that the user has recently signed in. See `auth/requires-recent-login` in https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For certain sensitive operations the Firebase Authentication API require that the user has recently (re)authenticated with their credentials.

There is currently no way to detect whether a specific call will require such re-authentication, nor documentation on how long the interval is before Firebase requires re-authentication.

The proper way to implement this, is to perform the operation, and catch errors. If the `error.code` is [`auth/requires-recent-login`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Error) ask the user to re-authenticate, call `reauthenticateWithCredential` with the fresh credentials, and then retry the operation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Frank, I will try to investigate this approach :)