# Catch certain Firebase Error in iOS not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

***Updated question***

I am trying to manually check if the user is has to be reauthenticated or not. This is what I've come up with:

```
    //MARK: updateEmail
static func updateEmail(email: String, finished: @escaping (_ done: Bool, _ hasToReauthenticate: Bool) -> Void) {
    let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
    currentUser?.updateEmail(to: email) { err in
        if err != nil {
            if let errCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: err!._code) {
                switch errCode {
                case .userTokenExpired:
                    print("expired")
                    finished(true, true)
                    break
                default:
                    Utilities.showErrorPopUp(labelContent: "Fehler", description: err!.localizedDescription)
                    finished(false, false)
                }
            }
        } else {
            finished(true, false)
        }
    }
}
```

But this is never going through the `.userTokenExpired` case even when it should.. What am I missing here ?

Comment: Such an API doesn't exist. What do you expect it to do? Where would you use this API? And what is keeping you from implementing it in your application code?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen How would I implement it?:D in my app the user can edit/delete its profile. And only if he really has to be reauthenticated I would like to promt the User with the login view

Comment: I thought about a workaround where I check for the error message and proceed depending on that but I couldnt really figure out how I would go that either

Comment: There is no API in Firebase Authentication that returns when the user has last authenticated, or whether that was recently. But since your application is making API calls when the user authenticates, you can also record the time when they do so, and then check whether that was recent enough for your use-case.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen what is  *recent enough*  ?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen hey Frank, did you have a look at the updated question ? can you maybe help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to check if user is authenicated - is same as reauthenication. Firebase will do their work to do some lower levels like tokens, etc. We don't have to worry about it.

```
guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
 //authenicate the user.
}
```

if you want to update the email address in user, the logic should be

check if the user is not nil, then update the email address.

If it is nil, then log in (anonymous or regular workflow to sign in), then update the email address.

I use this similar logic to check if the user is signed in, then do something. Otherwise, sign in as anonymous, then do same something.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API in Firebase Authentication that returns when the user has last authenticated, or whether that was recently. The only built-in functionality is that Firebase automatically checks for recent authentication for certain sensitive operations, but that seems to be of no use to you here.

But since your application is making API calls when the user authenticates, you can also record the time when they do so, and then check whether that was recent enough for your use-case.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Like I already asked in the comments, what is *recent enough* ?

Comment: and what about the idea of checking for the error ? Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: I think I found something.. trying it later: I can check for this `error`: `case .userTokenExpired:`

Comment: Isn't "recent enough" something **you** determine? Maybe we're dealing with a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here, as I'm struggling to understand what you're trying to accomplish with this code.

Comment: I thought Firebase decided after which time the user has to reauthenticate?

Comment: about the **XY Problem** , well the main question is still there, I just thought about a solution and wanted to let you know

Comment: It seems that you 're asking how to detect whether Firebase will require you to reauthenticate the user when calling a certain API. That was not at all obvious for me from anything so far, so you might want to say that in your question. The answer to that is that there's no API to do that, and you'll have to handle the exception you get back. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57964872/firebase-auth-manually-detect-if-the-current-user-has-recently-authenticated

Comment: sorry if that wasnt clear. I updated my question. Any idea ?

Comment: The proper way to handle the need for recent authentication is to catch the error that Firebase throws when it's not met. There is no way to pre-check whether that condition is met that I know of. See also the textual description here, that explains that: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user

Comment: but I am not pre-checking it, am I ? I am trying to catch the `error` but my code doesn't do that, but it goes into the `default` where it prints out the exact same `error-message` that is actually from the `error` it should catch. Am I making sense?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was quite simple: I caught the wrong `error`:

The error I have to catch in my case is `.requiresRecentLogin` . With that, everything is working fine.